# GdiPlus Bitmap covert to string

Tags: string, gdi+, hbitmap

Hey i'm working on a project and i want to send an image from a server to a client.

**How do i convert the picture from  GdiPlus bitmap to string.**

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Good for you. What's your question, what have you tried so far, and what specifically isn't working?

Comment: There isn't a question here. What do you need ? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could you get bytes from bitmap (or file) and convert them to a base64 string. The way is simple: just get data from image saving to memory and then convert to Base64.

```
Dim Stream As IO.MemoryStream
Dim Buffer As Byte() = New Byte() {}
Dim ImageString As String

Stream = New IO.MemoryStream()
Imagen.Save(Stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
Buffer = Stream.GetBuffer()
Stream.Close()

ImageString = System.Convert.ToBase64String(Buffer)
```

Are you working on unmanaged code? C# or VB.net?

Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't have it saved on file but I can convert it into Hbitmap if it helps